# Is it possible to have SQL append a string to a result given a certain set of conditions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an argument like this in my SQL query:

```
SELECT game, seasonNumber, leagueNumber, gameTitle
gameMaster AS GameLocation,
COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR, [gs].[pre_season_rank]), TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR,[gs].[season_rank]), TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR, [t].[overall_rank] )) AS Score
FROM GameStats gs
INNER JOIN Totals t
```

It works, but I need to change it so that the value of `gameTitle` has `2022_Season_Final_Ranking` appended to it
IF and ONLY IF `Score` has the value of `[t].[overall_rank]`

So the `gameTitle` column would look like this:

`Star Command Multiplayer_2022_Season_Final_Ranking` if the `Score` column gets its data from `[t].[overall_rank]`

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Just append the value to `overall_rank` then. SQL Server has 2 concatenation operators. `+` and `CONCAT`.

Comment: [Don't use `VARCHAR` without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @Larnu do you mean like this? `COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR, [gs].[pre_season_rank]), TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR,[gs].[season_rank]), TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR, [t].[overall_rank] + 'Multiplayer_2022_Season_Final_Ranking' )) AS Score` ?

Comment: @Larnu so I tried the above and it appends it to `Score`.  I need it appended to `gameTitle`...but only if `Score` uses `[overall_rank]`. If it uses `pre_season_rank` or `season_rank`, I don't want anything appended to `gameTitle`

Comment: Then use a `CASE` expression to only concatenate the value if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the query you have shown works, so you can modify it like this:

```sql
SELECT game, seasonNumber, leagueNumber, 
CASE WHEN COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [gs].[pre_season_rank]), TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[gs].[season_rank]), TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [t].[overall_rank])) = TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [t].[overall_rank]) THEN CONCAT(gameTitle, ' 2022_Season_Final_Ranking')  ELSE gameTitle END AS gameTitle, 
gameMaster AS GameLocation,
COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [gs].[pre_season_rank]), TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[gs].[season_rank]), TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [t].[overall_rank])) AS Score
FROM GameStats gs
INNER JOIN Totals t -- YOU HAVE NOT SHOWN THE JOIN CONDITION - DON'T FORGET IT!
```

I have made the assumption all the data can fix in a `VARCHAR(10)`. I am not sure why you are doing all the `TRY_CONVERT`s so I left them in. Also, you never showed the `JOIN` condition between `GameStats` and `Totals`, so make sure you add one.

You have to repeat the long `COALESCE` expression you use for `Score` since it is in the `SELECT` list - there is no shortcut.